# Can somebody help me with this linker error? I can't find a solution

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

```
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o obj/main.o -c /Users/ivencornils/Coding/main.cpp
g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -o Simplelist obj/main.o 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "print_list()", referenced from:
      print_menu(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >) in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [Simplelist] Error 1
```

Comment: @ven Cornils Do you have defined the function print_list?

Comment: yes I guess. I typed in:                                                        void print_menu(string name);
void print_list();
void add_item();
void delete_item();